# Slack API: files.upload: How to upload a file shared/posted to nowhere?

Tags: node.js, slack-api

All I want to do is:

1. Uploading a file without sharing/posting to any channel, just adding to my "Files".

   - I think it can be done on GUI app by unchecking the "Share with" checkbox when drag & dropping a file to the app.
   - I've tried files.upload API without "channels" argument however, such API calls won't upload the file, I confirmed it by seeing result of files.list which doesn't contain the file at all. Please note, with "channels" argument supplied, files are smoothly uploaded (and posted) by files.upload API.
2. Posting a message whose "attachments" has the file above as "image_url", or sharing the file to specific channel with a message though I don't know there are any APIs which realize it.

   - I think it can be done on GUI app by sharing a file from "Files" pane.

In other words, I'd like to upload a file without posting to any channel, and post a message with the file to some channel later.

Unfortunately the situation doesn't allow me to use any external file storage/hosting service, all the service I can reach and use is Slack itself only.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Of course you can upload files without sharing them in a channel with the API. Calling [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) without a channels property will do the trick. And if it does not work for you, you probably have an error in your code. Please add your code to the question, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Please also add to your response the response you get from the call to `files.upload` it should contain the file object as array incl. the file ID. You can then use the file ID with [`files.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.info) to double check that it worked.